# What value to assign to a char* in default constructor c++?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, default-constructor

I have a class `String` and I've made a field `char* name`, default, parameterized, copy constructor, destructor and overwritten `operator =`.

My question is how my default constructor should look like for a `char*`.

Below is part of my code. I use `char*` because the array should be dynamic:

```
class String {
    public:
        char* name;
        String(){
            name = new char[0];
        }
        String(char* str){
            name = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
            strcpy(name, str);
        }
```

Comment: Your second constructor makes a null terminated string, so you can make a good argument that your first constructor should do the same `name = new char[1]; name[0] = '\0';` Having both constructors produce the same result will simplify the rest of the code. But setting `name = nullptr;` will make constructing an empty sting more efficient, but then having two cases will then complicate the rest of your code. It's your choice.

Comment: @john Instead just `name = new char[1]();` would be fine.

Comment: You should be using a pointer and a length instead of a null terminated string, in which case the obvious answer is `nullptr`.

Comment: However your constructors produce two different results with no way to distinguish between them later, so that cannot be right.

Comment: Also, you should probably change `char*` to `const char*`, though strcpy won't work then.

Comment: @user12002570 `const char* str` would be fine, but `name` needs to be mutable.

Answer (score 1):

First, the constructor taking a `char*` should really take a `const char*` or otherwise you won't be able to create `String`s from string literals:

```cpp
String(const char* str) : name(new char[std::strlen(str) + 1]) {
    std::strcpy(name, str);
}
```

The default constructor could then simply delegate construction to the constructor taking a `const char*`:

```cpp
String() : String("") {}
```

As per the logic in the constructor taking a `const char*`, the default constructor will then allocate memory for *one* `char` which will hold the value of `\0`.

---

Though, I would recommend to not use a raw owning pointer but to instead use a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` or `std::vector<char>` to help with the memory management. If you use a `unique_ptr` you could also add member variables for holding the length/size of the string and also its capacity. If you use a `std::vector`, you can just make proxy member functions for the `vector`s `size()` and `capacity()` member functions. [Example using a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`](https://godbolt.org/z/d47r5qT43).

Comment: Although the other answer seem correct to me as well, this one is more educative (especially the final recommendation).

Comment: imho its not good advice to allocate memory in the default constructor. Why not simply `name(nullptr)` ? There is no need to store a nullterminator when the string is empty. As soon as a single character is added anyhow reallocation is required. Consider eg `std::vector<String> x(500);`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That would mean that the state would have to be checked in every function. `begin()`/`end()`/ `operator<<` etc. I think that would be rather costly. If we added SSO to this `String` it'd be a non-issue though.

Answer (score 0):

> how my default constructor should look like for a char*.

You can make a null-terminated array of length one. Also note that you should use *member initializer list* as shown below:

```
//use member iniializer list
String():name( new char[1]())
//------------------------^^---->note these parentheses to null terminate
{
}
//use member initializer list
String(char* str):name(new char[strlen(str) + 1])
{
    strcpy(name, str);
}
```

Comment: I agree there's nothing wrong with the answer. +1. If somebody thinks it's incorrect I'd be happy to learn why.

Comment: @wohlstad Thanks, I too am ready to delete the answer(or update it) if there's anything wrong with it.